# What do these toasts mean? «Que en salud se le convierta.», «Con las mismas finezas pago.»

Tags: significado, coloquialismos

Buscando la Internet, solo encuentro referencias al texto original, *El Cuaderno de Maya*. ¿Son éstos coloquialismos? El contexto es una lista de brindis, ofrecido por costumbre por la oradora.

> «Que en salud se le convierta.»
>
> «Con las mismas finezas pago.»

Contexto completo:

> Los hombres colocaron el refrigerador en el sitio correspondiente, lo
> conectaron al gas y luego se instalaron a compartir un par de botellas
> de vino y un salmón que Manuel había ahumado la semana anterior en un
> tambor metálico con leña de manzano.
> Mirando el mar por la ventana, bebieron y comieron mudos, las únicas
> palabras que pronunciaron fueron una serie de elaborados y
> ceremoniosos brindis: «¡Salud!». **«Que en salud se le convierta.» «Con
> las mismas finezas pago.»** «Que viva usted muchos años.» «Que asista
> usted a mi sepelio.» Manuel me lanzaba miradas de reojo, incómodo,
> hasta que lo llamé aparte para decirle que se tranquilizara, que no
> pensaba abalanzarme sobre las botellas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienen pinta de ser expresiones para brindar (o para decir antes de comer, al estilo de "qué aproveche") propias de determinados países de Hispanoamérica. Aquí en España nunca las había escuchado.

La primera al parecer no es nueva:

> *Fray Gómez metió la mano derecha dentro de la manga izquierda, y sacó un par de pejerreyes tan fresquitos que parecían acabados de salir del mar.
>
>   —Aquí los tiene su paternidad, y que en salud se le conviertan. Voy a guisarlos.*
>
> Ricardo Palma, "Tradiciones peruanas, séptima serie", 1889 (Perú).

En este caso se percibe que el que expresa el deseo espera que lo que su interlocutor va a degustar se transforme en salud para él/ella (es decir, que no le siente mal).

La segunda expresión es interesante, no encuentro más coincidencias que la del libro (puede que sea un brindis inventado expresamente para el personaje). Si la analizamos, tenemos por un lado:

> **[fineza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HxvBc65)**
>
> 1. f. Pureza y bondad de algo en su línea.
> 2. f. Acción o dicho con que alguien da a entender el amor y benevolencia que tiene a otra persona.
> 3. f. Actividad y empeño amistoso a favor de alguien.
> 4. f. Dádiva pequeña y de cariño.
> 5. f. Delicadeza y primor.

Y por otro lado tenemos que en algunos países de Sudamérica (el diccionario menciona el oeste de Bolivia, que linda con Perú y Chile, país este origen de la novela) el verbo *[pagar](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pagar)* se usa como:

> Corresponder alguien bebiendo la misma cantidad de una bebida alcohólica que otra persona ha bebido anteriormente en su honor.

Por lo que el brindis queda algo así como "tú has tenido la delicadeza de beber un trago por mí, así que yo te ofrezco la misma delicadeza y bebo por ti". Ninguna de las dos suena coloquial, es más, parecen bastante formales y de buen gusto.

Comment: Buen hallazgo en el primero. La segunda podría ser difícil encontrar en contexto porque quizá relaciona con una referencia más tarde "Los hombres terminaron el salmón y el vino, se despidieron y se fueron. Me
llamó la atención que Manuel no hiciera amago de pagarles, como tampoco lo hizo
con los otros que lo habían ayudado antes a transportar el refrigerador, pero habría
sido imprudente por mi parte preguntarle sobre ello."

Answer (score 3):

"Coloquialismo" en el sentido de informal, no (por lo menos, *no necesariamente*).

Una forma coloquial/infirmal de hacer un brindis es

> Arriba [el vaso], abajo, al centro y pa'dentro!

La primera fórmula que indicas no me parece informal. Es bastante frecuente desear a otros, especialmetne en ocasiones especiales (durante las que realizarías algún tipo de brindis) `Salud, dinero y amor`. Para ambos ejemplos faltaría un poco más de contexto, pero básicamente el primero está deseando salud:

> Que [lo que sea] se convierta en salud
>
> Que este trago/esta copa de vino se convierta en salud
>
> Brindamos por [la razón que sea] que en salud se le convierta a *user135711*

La segunda me parece una fórmula para dar las gracias, en el sentido de "tú me has ayudado a mí y ahora quiero devolverte el favor"

[Finezas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HxvBc65)

> 2. f. Acción o dicho con que alguien da a entender el amor y benevolencia que tiene a otra persona.
>
> Actividad y empeño amistoso a favor de alguien.

por lo que la segunda frase significa

> Con **el mismo gesto de  amor** pago (de vuelta)
>
> Fulano: Brindemos Mengano, que este trago de vino en salud se convierta
>
> Mengano: Gracias Fulano, con las mismas finezas pago

En este ejemplo *Mengano* usa una fórmula tipo "gracias a usted también", "lo mismo digo", "lo mismo para usted", etc.